# Converting geocentric coordinates to geodetic coordinates?

Tags: gps, geodetic, spheroid

I would like to start by saying that I am very new to this. 
I have 160 different points which all have similar layout as below:

at point | X= 153346.357 | Y=354912.111 | Z=0 |

Doing some research I believe that these are geocentric coordinates. What is the formula which uses the above information (and the Datum: WGS 84) in order to convert these values to geodetic coordinates (i.e. GPS coordinates in the forms of DMS)?

Comment: Those coordinates are in a *projected* coordinate reference system. You need to know what the coordinate reference system is before you can convert them to lat/long coordinates.

Comment: If you don't know what CRS your data is in, one way to find out (by trial and error) is to take a known point location (one where you know its coordinates in this CRS and its coordinates in lat/long) and use the EPSG.io coordinate transformer to convert the coordinates of that point into lat/long using different transformations until you find the one that gives the correct lat/long. https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=25000&t_srs=4326